# Nuxtjs SSR middleware loop does not cause error?

Tags: javascript, node.js, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering

I'm working with nuxtjs2 in ssr mode. I created an middleware to check if user has the valid token then i will redirect them to the private page, if not then i will redirect them to home page. The thing is if i redirect them to home page, it should cause an infinite loop but i doesn't. Anyone know why this work normally ?

```
export default async ({ route, store, redirect, $repositories }) => {
    const res = await $repositories.repository.getUserProfile()
    if(res.data){
        redirect('/private-profile');
    }else{
        redirect('/');
    }
};
```